# Boolean Condition in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I'm new to php and mySQL. Basically I have a table of users and I want to echo the id, name and surname of the users if their "valid" integer is equal to 1, here is my attempt;

```
<?php
$servername = "aaa";
$username = "aaa";
$password = "aaa";
$dbname = "aaa";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Surname, Valid FROM myTable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($row["Valid"] = 1) {echo "id: " . $row["ID"]. " - Name: " . $row["Name"]. " " . $row["Surname"]. "<br>";
    }
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Using this code gives me a list of all the users, even though their valid integers are zero.

Thanks,

Comment: Use strict comparison operator(`===`), like this:  `if($row['Valid'] === 1){ ...`

Comment: May i ask what's the valid row for?

Comment: Dear @ern, Im just trying to learn the basics but I plan to use it similar to deleting a row. Rather than deleting it, I will change the valid bit to zero so that I can access the old information.

Comment: Then just `$row['Valid']` should work for you as an argument in your statement..Since 0 means false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP to check for conditions as you are you need the == operator instead of the = operator. All you are doing is setting all the valid columns to 1.

```
if($row["Valid"] == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a `WHERE` condition to your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Surname, Valid FROM myTable WHERE Valid=1";
```

If you query select all fields of table, you can also perform the query as:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Valid=1";
```

#### Edit:

As suggested by my dears and accurate *censors* in the comments below, if you use my suggested solution, the check of `$row[Valid]` in the `while` loop, although not invalidate the result, is totally unnecessary.

So - to obtain the list of users with field `Valid` = 1, you can write in this simple way:

```
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() )
{
    echo "id: " . $row["ID"]. " - Name: " . $row["Name"]. " " . $row["Surname"]. "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Though this certainly does make sense it does _not_ answer the question in a strict sense...

Comment: where is not required for any queries.  If where is excluded, it will match all rows.

Comment: @arkascha yes, you are right

Comment: @Devon yes, I know! I have interpreted «I want to echo» as «I want to select». Please note that the result is anyway the same

Comment: then you'd need to tell the OP not to use their intended comparison in conjunction with your answer. They may not know what to do with your answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- as commanded!